# How to run multiple projects from a GitHub clone

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a game that has both a Client and a Server. But I'm unable to run both of them at the same time without having two instances of Visual Studio open. I cannot find a way to select multiple startup items. The .sln files for both the Client and the Server are in different folders, how do I do this?

I tried following the steps that GitHub provides https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects.md but since the .sln files are in different folders, there's no way to select both of them as a startup project.
Edit: This is a local repository, not remote.

Comment: Not a github/repo question. Multiple startup items is about multiple projects within a single solution. You can run these programs simultaneously without VS at all. I think you need more detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve. Are you wanting to _debug_ them both at the same time? What's the issue with using two instances of VS?

Comment: Add the projects to a single solution (you can have duplicate solutions just for this purpose) and you can "Set Startup Projects" and pick both.

Comment: I'd like to be able to just open up visual studio and run the projects simultaneously from within the repository instead of having to open up both projects at the same time, does that make sense?

Comment: Visual Studio will open one solution at a time. A solution contains a set of projects. If you must use two solutions, then you need two instances of Visual Studio. But a project can be in multiple solutions. If you create a new solution and add the relevant projects to that solution, then you will be able to choose multiple startup projects as described in the document that you referenced.